# For which polynomials is NTT faster than Karatsuba?

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, asymptotics

I'm thinking about to learn the number theoretic transformation (NTT), but that only makes sense, if it is faster (means less multiplications than Karatsuba) for polynomials of degree 4, 11 and/or 16.

Does anyone knows any measure for that NTT-Method and maybe a nice tutorial? Does anyone know about the big-O complexity?